# G is finite group such that H is normal and P is a Sylow p-subgroup of H

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

So, suppose that $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is normal subgroup and $P$ is a Sylow $p-$subgroup of $H$. Then prove that there exist $Q$ a Sylow $p-$subgroup of $G$ such that $Q\leq N_G(P)$. Honestly, I don't know how tackle the problem. Just to know that $[G:N_G(P)]=[H:N_H(P)]$ :-(

Comment: Is $P$ a $p$-Sylow of $H$?

Comment: There is something wrong in the formulation.

Comment: Something's weird here: you give $\,H\lhd G\,$, but thereafter you don't use $\,H\,$ anymore...?

Comment: Nancy, $P$ is the unique Sylow p-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, so you must reformulate your question correctly. Since $H$ is normal, $Q:= P \cap H$ is a Sylow p-subgroup of $H$, but $Q$ also lies in $N_H(P)$, hence it is a Sylow p-subgroup of $N_H(P)$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Seirios: I am terribly sorry. I edited it. Your right.

Comment: As $H$ is normal in $G$, $G$ acts on the set $\mathrm{Syl}_p(H)$ of Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ (by conjugation). Restricting the action to a $p$-Sylow $Q$ of $G$ you get a $p$-group acting on a set of order coprime to $p$. This implies that $Q$ has a fixed point $P_0$, i.e., $Q$ normalizes $P_0$. Now $P_0 = P^h$ for some $h\in H$ gives the $p$-Sylow $Q^{h^{-1}}$ of $G$ normalizing $P$.

Comment: @NickyHekster can you please explain why $H$ being normal implies $Q:= P \cap H$ is a Sylow p-subgroup of $H$?

Comment: @John11 In general, if $H \unlhd G$, then the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H$ are exactly $H \cap P$, $P \in Syl_p(G)$. This is a standard fact from Sylow theory and is not hard to prove. If $H$ is not normal, this is no longer true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $Q$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$ containing $P$ (using the Sylow containment theorem in $N_G(P)$). We claim that $Q$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, that is, that $[G:Q]$ is not divisible by $p$. Indeed, $[G:Q] = [G:N_G(P)][N_G(P):Q] = [H:N_H(P)] [N_G(P):Q]$. The first factor $[H:N_H(P)]$ is not divisible by $p$ since $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. The second factor $[N_G(P):Q]$ is not divisible by $p$ since $Q$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$. Since $p$ is prime and divides neither factor, it does not divide their product, $[G:Q]$.

Comment: Nice - and the normality of $H$ is used in the fact that $[G:N_G(P)]=[H:N_H(P)]$ since the Frattini argument yields $G=HN_G(P)$, right?

Comment: @NickyHekster: yes, exactly.